# Access iphone’s settings app on real device

Tags: appium, appium-ios, python-appium

I want to access device settings, I checked there are similar posts but no answer for real device.

I tried passing parameters as

`desired_caps['app'] = 'settings'` and `desired_caps['bundleId'] = 'com.apple.Preferences'`

But I get error `Instruments Trace Error : Target failed to run: Permission to debug com.apple.Preferences was denied.` The app must be signed with a development identity (e.g. iOS Developer).

Seems like above works on simulator but not device.

I can launch my test app, so I'm passing other parameters correctly.

Or is there any other way to access device settings?

```
desired_caps = dict()
desired_caps['platformName'] = 'iOS'
desired_caps['platformVersion'] = '9.2.1'
desired_caps['deviceName'] = 'iPhone'
desired_caps['udid'] = '09d905a'
desired_caps['app'] = 'settings'
# desired_caps['bundleId'] = 'com.apple.Preferences'
# desired_caps['fullReset'] = True
desired_caps['newCommandTimeout'] = 1000
config_iOS.driver_settings = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)
```

Answer (score 0):

For check all the info related to device you can use ios-deploy library. As per my knowledge you are Missing something. Can you attach appium logs.?

Comment: here is same issue in details https://discuss.appium.io/t/can-appium-access-and-operate-iphones-settings-page/2519/11

Comment: While running the script make sure that your xcode should open. Let me know after that it works.

Comment: not sure xcode being open is related but i tried my keeping xcode open but same issue

Comment: app path? I edited question to add parameters which i'm setting. These works for my test app but not for in build app

Comment: I am not getting what you are trying to say. Please specify your problem in detail.

Comment: I can launch my test app but not in built app. I'm trying to open ios `Settings` and edit. But when I try to open it, passing as `app` I get above error.

Comment: Can you please ios-deploy library?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to automate application which is on profile other than development. As the error says Settings application settings application of the application is build with development profile.

So the first moment when you try to fetch any element it will show the error.

In short, You can't automate application downloaded from app store/system application or installed with release mode using Appium.